# How to Populate 2 strings in Listview from webservice?

Tags: java, android, web-services, listview

Am an newbie to android ...kindly help me guys...I have 2 strings in my sample webservice(Not in an array) and I want to populate it in the listview .I wrote code to populate with a single string.But I don't know how to populate with 2nd strings below to 1st string in listview.Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Here is my complete code

HTTPURLCONNECT

```
class HttpULRConnect  {

    public static String getData(String uri){

        BufferedReader reader = null;

        try {

            URL url = new URL(uri);

            HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));

            Log.d("testhtt2","test");

            String line;

            while ((line= reader.readLine())!=null) {

                sb.append(line+"\n");
            }
            Log.d("test44", sb.toString());

            return sb.toString();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }

        finally{
            if (reader!=null) {
                try {
                    reader.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
 e.printStackTrace();
                    return null;
                }
            }
        }}}
```

Here is my FETCH.java

public class Fetch extends Activity {

```
    ArrayList<Flowers> flowersList = new ArrayList<Flowers>();

    String url ="http://113.193.30.155/MobileService/MobileService.asmx/GetSampleData";

    @Override

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.fetch);

        new BackTask().execute(url);

    }

    public class BackTask extends AsyncTask<String,String,String>{

        @Override

        protected void onPreExecute() {

            super.onPreExecute();

        }

        @Override

        protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {

            String content =HttpULRConnect.getData(url);

            return content;

        }

        @Override

        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {

            try {

                JSONArray ar = new JSONArray(s);

                for (int i = 0; i < ar.length(); i++) {

                    JSONObject jsonobject = ar.getJSONObject(i);
                    Flowers flowers = new Flowers();

                    flowers.setName(jsonobject.getString("NAME"));

                    flowersList.add(flowers);
                }

            }

            catch (JSONException e){

                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            FlowerAdapter adapter = new FlowerAdapter(Fetch.this, R.layout.flower_lis_item, flowersList);
            ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);

            lv.setAdapter(adapter);

        }

    }



    static class Flowers  {

        public String getName() {

            return NAME;

        }

        public void setName(String name) {

            this.NAME = name;

        }


        private String NAME;

    }



    public static class FlowerAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Flowers> {

        private  ArrayList<Flowers> items;

        private Context mContext;

        public FlowerAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceID, ArrayList<Flowers> items){

            super(context,textViewResourceID,items);

            mContext = context;

            this.items = items;

        }

        @Override

        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

            View v = convertView;

            Flowers flowers = items.get(position);

            if(v==null){

                LayoutInflater inflater =(LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

                v=inflater.inflate(R.layout.flower_lis_item,null);

            }

            TextView title = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.textView3);
            TextView text =(TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.textView2);

            if (title != null) {

                title.setText(flowers.getName());
                text.setText(flowers.getName());
            }
            return v;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, but your question is unclear. Where do you want to use second String?

Comment: I want to display my 2nd string below to 1st string in listview